# Segmentation fault:11. In need for solving code (Linked List)

Tags: c++

I am currently a beginner with C++, transferring from C. But I am still a beginner at programming codes.

I am currently looking for someone who can help me find the problem with my source code (actually, it's from a friend). The source code seems to be running fine at my friend's compiler (Windows), but I am currently using VSCode on MacOS Big Sur.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Data_mhs{
    char nim[12];
    char nilai;
};
struct mhs{
    Data_mhs data;
    mhs* next;
};

mhs* head;
mhs* tail;
mhs* baru;
mhs* del;

void inisialisasi(){
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
}

void input(Data_mhs br)
{
    baru->data = br; //penugasan struktur
    baru->next = NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head = baru;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = baru;
        tail=baru;
    }
}

void hapus(){
    mhs simpan;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n(DATA TIDAK ADA YANG DIHAPUS)"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        simpan.data  = head->data;
        cout<<"\nData yang dihapus adalah ";
        cout<<simpan.data.nim<<"||"<<simpan.data.nilai<<endl;

        //hapus depan
        del = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete del;
    }
}

void menu(){
    char pilih, ulang;
    mhs tmp; 
start:
    cout<<"\nMenu : "<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Input data"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Hapus data"<<endl;
    cout<<"Masukkan pilihan Anda : ";
    cin>>pilih;
    switch(pilih)
    {
        case '1' :
            fflush(stdin);
            cout<<"\nMasukkan NIM  : ";
            cin>>tmp.data.nim;
            cout<<"Masukkan nilai : ";
            cin>>tmp.data.nilai;

            input(tmp.data);
            break;
        case '2' :
            hapus();
            break;
        default :
            cout<<"Pilihan salah"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\nKembali ke menu (y/n) ?";
    cin>>ulang;
    if(ulang=='y'){
        goto start;
    }
}

int main(){
    inisialisasi();
    menu();

    return 0;
}
```

The code seems to be running fine, but there seems to be something wrong with the code while running on my compiler (MacOS), the code shows "Segmentation Fault:11"

[image]

There seems to be a problem at:

```cpp
baru->data = brr; //penugasan struktur
baru->next = NULL;
```

It would be a great help if someone could help give a solution to my problem!

Comment: You're using `#include <iostream>`. That means that this is C++ and not C

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you can reproduce the error (that is, get the same error each time you run the code), then please find the simplest input that will cause the error, then hard-code that input into your code.

Comment: It appears `baru` is initially null and cannot be set before it is referenced. That would account for your seg fault.

Comment: _Sorry for the messy tabs though_ No need for that, see (amongst others): http://format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: In C++, use [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (double-linked list) or [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) (single-linked list) instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Pointless advice when the assignment is very likely to implement the list yourself.

Comment: @sweenish You are *assuming* this is a class assignment. The OP said this code is "from a friend". I'd hate to see a student turn in someone else's work for credit...

Comment: I always assume someone writing a data structure from scratch is doing homework. And cheaters are stupid enough to take their stolen code online. They're cheating; they're obviously not smart.

Comment: @sweenish Well, there might be "real world" problems, which force you to do it, well, not _"from scratch"_, but using well thought examples (and not standard c++). I had such a case, when we needed to implement fixed sized queues for portable use in various embedded systems, from very small bare metal to fully fleged uC Linux systems. Similarly we did for linked lists (intrinsic next/prev node pointers for `T`) So don't _assume_ (though I certainly never had such problems in doind it correctly :-D )

Comment: Which only supports my original point that recommending `std::list` was pointless advice.

Answer (score 5):

You never allocated `baru` to point to anything. When you do `baru->data = brr;` you are dereferencing a null pointer. It is null because global pointers are initialized to null.